# Multiple INSERT statements with one SELECT in one query GBQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have one big table I want to select data from and I do not want to query it twice. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
WITH data AS 
(
    SELECT row1 
    FROM BIG_TABLE
)
INSERT INTO table1 (SELECT * FROM data WHERE row1 = 'a')
INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT * FROM data WHERE row1 = 'b')
```

Currently GBQ doesn't let me put the CTE `data` outside the `INSERT` statement, so my query is not possible, is there any way to achieve this desired result?

Comment: How about using single insert statement with a union ?

Are you fine with it ?

Comment: @Tushar that would not insert the data into two different tables

Comment: @extrawhitecitrus I proposed you an answer, have you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, you can't write a CTE in multiple insert statement, because in the `insert` the CTE should be a part of the select query.

If you don't want to repeat the query and write the logic once :

- Solution 1 : create a View

You can create a view, example :

```sql
CREATE VIEW `project.dataset.job_failure_view` AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `prpject.dataset.job_failure`
);

INSERT INTO `project.dataset.job_failure` (SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.job_failure_view` WHERE job_name = 'a');
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.job_failure` (SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.job_failure_view` WHERE job_name = 'b');
```

- Solution 2 : Create a temp Table

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE `project.dataset.job_failure_view` AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `prpject.dataset.job_failure`
);

INSERT INTO `project.dataset.job_failure` (SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.job_failure_view` WHERE job_name = 'a');
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.job_failure` (SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.job_failure_view` WHERE job_name = 'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNIOB ALL. It allows you to insert data into multiple table, with different filter and combine the results of multiple select statements instead of a CTE.

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE row1 = 'a'
UNION ALL
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE row1 = 'b'
```

Comment: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT but got keyword INSERT - does not seem to work